# Using html file for login page in spring oauth2 instead of ftl templates

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-oauth2

I am trying a Spring Oauth2 application similar to https://github.com/spring-guides/tut-spring-security-and-angular-js/tree/master/oauth2 .
Everything is same except the custom login page where i used standard html instead of ftl.

The application throws a 403 error after I submit the custom login form. It works fine with Oauth2 built-in form.

Here is the authorization server code:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableEurekaClient
@EnableResourceServer
@SessionAttributes("authorizationRequest")
public class AuthApplication extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(AuthApplication.class, args);
}

@Override
public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addViewController("/login")
    .setViewName("forward:/index.html");
    registry.addViewController("/oauth/confirm_access")
    .setViewName("authorize");

}
@Configuration
@Order(-20)
protected static class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .formLogin().loginPage("/login").permitAll()
            .and().authorizeRequests()
            .anyRequest().authenticated();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.parentAuthenticationManager(authenticationManager);
    }

}
@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
protected static class OAuth2AuthorizationConfig extends
        AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @Bean
    public JwtAccessTokenConverter jwtAccessTokenConverter() {
        JwtAccessTokenConverter converter = new JwtAccessTokenConverter();
        KeyPair keyPair = new KeyStoreKeyFactory(
                new ClassPathResource("keystore.jks"),
                "foobar".toCharArray())
                .getKeyPair("test");
                converter.setKeyPair(keyPair);
        return converter;
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws
    Exception {
        clients.inMemory()
                .withClient("acme")
                .secret("acmesecret")
                .authorizedGrantTypes("authorization_code", "refresh_token",
                        "password").scopes("openid").autoApprove(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints)
            throws Exception {
    endpoints.authenticationManager(authenticationManager)
    .accessTokenConverter(
                jwtAccessTokenConverter());
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer oauthServer)
            throws Exception {
        oauthServer.tokenKeyAccess("permitAll()").checkTokenAccess(
                "isAuthenticated()");
    }
}
}
```

Here is the index.html:

```
<body>
<div class="container">
<form role="form" action="login" method="post">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="username">Username:</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="username"
 name="username"/>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="password">Password:</label>
        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password"
 name="password"/>
    </div>
    <input type="hidden" id="csrf_token" name="${_csrf.parameterName}"
    value="${_csrf.token}"/>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
    </form>
   </div>
   </body>
```